# java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, gwt, oracle10g, ejb

I started to develop an application in GWT. First I tried a simple login. When user hits the login button, an async call checks on server if the username and password are in the database.
When I run this on server side only (in a simple main() method) it works fine. But when I try it in my browser with GWT (which actually call the same method at last) it throws the following exception (in short):

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Error Code: 17002`

I noticed that `EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(...)` is ok, exception is thrown on `EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer at last. When I started developing my application, I generated sample code. I left checked "Use Google App Engine". Now started again the whole project without GAE and it works.
I'm learning GWT and honestly don't know what is GAE for. I just clicked "next-next-finish" and wasn't aware of the danger...